# Error Using fpurge(stdin);

Tags: c, string, ubuntu-14.04

Here is the Part of the program that i am trying to compile using gcc compiler on ubuntu 14.04.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main() {
    int i;
    char str[50], pat[3];
    char sep;
    printf("Enter the sting to seperate\n ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    fpurge(stdin);
    printf("Enter the patern in Numbers to seperate Example : 1 2 3\n");
    //__fpurge(stdin);
    scanf("%s", pat);
    fpurge(stdin);
    printf("Enter the seperator Example: ; or enter ,space");
    scanf("%c", &sep);
}
```

this is the Error:

```
 /tmp/cc0bHLkO.o: In function `main':
 str_sepert.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `fpurge'
 str_sepert.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `fpurge'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: According to [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fpurge) `fpurge` is not available under Linux. You'll have to write your own. Also note on that page: *Usually it is a mistake to want to discard input buffers.*

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used "__fpurge()"  and problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fpurge` is not in the standard C library. It is nonstandard and not
portable. It is a BSD function.

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/845246-fpurge

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used "__fpurge()"  and problem solved.

Comment: I should have added you could update your `include`'s to get the function you want but it seems you already know that now.

Comment: I got more explanation from that link you gave.thank you.